# How to provide auxiliary document that (a) uses citations in main document and (b) has own additional literature?

Tags: citing, multibib, xr

I am trying to create an appendix (`appendix.tex`) that:

1. Refers back to sections and citations in a paper (`paper.tex`)
2. Maintains the same identifiers for the citations found in the paper, for instance [1], [2].
3. Adds some additional citations not found in the paper with a separate numbering scheme, for instance [A1], [A2].
4. (I am not sure if that is important, but I am using different document classes for the main document and the appendix.)

I know about the `xr` and `multibib` packages, but cannot get them working together properly.

**Problem 1:**

Either I do not add the bibliography.bib to appendix.tex, then all references not used in the main paper are unresolved (show up as question marks).

Or I add bibliography.bib to appendix.tex, then that messes messes up the identifiers (in the example below Doe should remain [1] and Smith should remain [2] since these are the identifiers in the output produced from paper.tex.

**Problem 2:**

`Section~\ref{sec:intro}` should produce "Section 1" but produces "Section 1Introductionsection.1"

Any hints on what I might try?

I have experimented with `multibib` but could not get the in-text citations labelled properly (the additional references in the bibliography where correctly labelled as A1, A2, but in text they were still showing as [1] and [2] not [A1] and [A2].

**paper.tex (with bibliography.bib)**

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
    @Book{Smith2000,
      author    = {Mary Smith},
      title     = {First Book},
      year      = {2000},
    }
    
    @Book{Doe2001,
      author    = {John Doe},
      title     = {Another Book},
      year      = {2001},
    }
    
    @Book{Alpha2010,
      author  = {Alice Alpha},
      title   = {Some Book},
      year    = {2010},
    }
    
    @Book{Bravo2011,
      author  = {Beatrice Bravo},
      title   = {Some Other Book},
      year    = {2011},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\title{The Paper}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

Citation in paper \cite{Smith2000,Doe2001}.

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

**appendix.tex**

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{paper}

\begin{document}

\title{The Appendix}
\maketitle


\section{Comments}

See introduction (Section~\ref{sec:intro}).

Sources used only in the appendix \cite{Alpha2010,Bravo2011}.

Referring to same literature as paper \cite{Smith2000,Doe2001}.

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: I'd recommend to draft a `master.tex` file, and `\include` the "slaves" `paper.tex` and `appendix.tex` files with [docmute](https://ctan.org/pkg/docmute).